# text mark from value in table

Tags: pgfplots

I can use the following to get a plot with the value of one of the
columns as the marker in the plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c
  1,1,bob
  2,2,joe
  3,3,fred
  }\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scatter,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    scatter/classes={
      bob={mark=text, /pgf/text mark={bob}},
      joe={mark=text, /pgf/text mark={joe}},
      fred={mark=text, /pgf/text mark={fred}}
    }]
    \addplot+ table [x=a,y=b,meta=c]{\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Having to enter all that `scatter/classes={...}` code isn't very
efficient, and isn't feasible for lots of data.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively use `nodes near coords` directly, set their alignment to `center`, and remove the markers with `mark=none`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c
  1,1,bob
  2,2,joe
  3,3,fred
  }\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scatter,
    only marks,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align=center
]
    \addplot+ [mark=none] table [x=a,y=b,meta=c]{\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This produces the desired result.

You have to clear `nodes near coords` to prevent column c from being parsed as number. The options for marks must be given to `\addplot`, because with no options some defaults are set. And the content of column c is stored in `\pgfplotspointmeta`, which can be given as argument to `text mark`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
  a,b,c
  1,1,bob
  2,2,joe
  3,3,fred
  }\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[scatter,
        nodes near coords=, % clear it, otherwise column c will be treated as number
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
  ]
  \addplot+[only marks,mark=text,   % marks must be set here to overwrite default settings
      text mark=\pgfplotspointmeta, % contains the text
  ] table [x=a,y=b,meta=c]{\data};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```